# Increase auto-suspend time in Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code

I've just created a new Visual Studio Online environment. I'm trying to find a way to edit the auto-suspend time (see image below) to no avail. Is is possible to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PM for VS Online here...

Unfortunately, this is currently a known limitation. We’re working to make this setting editable. The workaround, for right now, is to re-create the environment with the auto-suspend setting you’d like.